# Symfony - test properly voter class

Tags: php, symfony, phpunit, tdd, acl

I have trouble writing test for my custom **voter** in *Symfony* as I am new at writing test:

This is part of the code I want to test:

```
protected function voteOnAttribute(
    string $attribute,
    $subject,
    TokenInterface $token
): bool
{
    $user = $token->getUser();
    if (!$user instanceof UserInterface) {
        return false;
    }

    return match ($attribute) {
        'read'   => $this->canRead($member, $subject),
        'create' => $this->canCreate($member, $subject),
        default  => throw new Exception(sprintf('Unhandled attribute "%s"', $attribute))
    };
}
```

And this is my test class:

```
protected $token;

public function setUp(): void
{
    $this->token = $this->createMock(TokenInterface::class);
    $this->token
        ->method('getUser')
        ->willReturn([
            'fistName' => 'Jonh',
            'lastName' => 'Doe',
            'email' => 'johndoe@socialhp.com'
        ]);
}

/**
 * @dataProvider provideCases
 */
public function testVote(
    array $attributes,
    string $subject,
    ?TokenInterface $token,
    $expectedVote
) {
    $voter = new RoleVoter();
    $this->assertEquals($expectedVote, $voter->vote($this->token, $subject, $attributes));
}

public function provideCases(): \Generator
{
    yield 'user cannot read' => [
        ['read'],
        'customers',
        $this->token,
        VoterInterface::ACCESS_DENIED,
    ];

    yield 'user can read' => [
        ['read'],
        'customers',
        $this->token,
        VoterInterface::ACCESS_GRANTED,
    ];
}
```

And I always get:

> testVote with data set "user can read" (array('read'), 'customers',
> null, 1) Failed asserting that -1 matches expected 1.

I would really appreciate if someone would help me continue with this.. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You didn't stubbed this method `$token->getUser()`.
As you're defining `$token` as a [test double](https://phpunit.readthedocs.io/en/9.5/test-doubles.html#test-doubles), a [stub](https://phpunit.readthedocs.io/en/9.5/test-doubles.html#test-doubles) to be accurate, you're somehow forced to describe every interaction with it, otherwise the testing framework (should be phpunit in this case, if I'm not mistaking), will return `null` for every not-defined interaction (method call).

> By default, all methods of the original class are replaced with a dummy implementation that returns null (without calling the original method). Using the will($this->returnValue()) method, for instance, you can configure these dummy implementations to return a value when called.

(from [docs](https://phpunit.readthedocs.io/en/9.5/test-doubles.html#stubs))

You need to write something like

```
$this->token
 ->method('getUser')
 ->willReturn($user);
```

where `$user` is another test double you need to create.

As a conclusion, I suggest to test also the case where `$token->getUser()` returns `null` (that's basically what you're already doing here, inadvertently

Comment: I have edited my post adding that part of the code missing. Still when dumpin results of $token in the testVote() method, I still get null and same fail as before.. :/ @DonCallisto

Comment: @yaraw69 `getUser` should return something like `@return string|\Stringable|UserInterface` not an array.